# ArcPy script causing python.exe to stop working (memory issue?)

Tags: arcpy, memory, python.exe-stopped-working

I have a script written in Python that uses ArcPy to create maps of the kernel densities of thousands of datasets. Each dataset is relatively small, but there about 50,000 sets in total.

When I run my script, it stops after about 10-15 minutes and gives the "python.exe has stopped working" popup. The Windows 7 event viewer tells me it is an Exception Code 0x0000005, which appears to be an access violation. The datasets the code works on are not the same each time, so it is not a specific set that is causing the problem.

Watching the task manager when the script is running, I noticed that python.exe is increasing its memory usage every few seconds, which makes me believe there is a memory leak somewhere. I thought Python had garbage collection? Is there something that arcPy is doing?

**EDIT**:
So I tracked down the part of my code causing the problem, but I don't know HOW it is leaking. I think I am cleaning everything up. Does anyone spot something I missed?

```
def makeMap(asno, isKdens):
try:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("F:\\testFiles\\testMap.mxd")   ###Reference to basemap document
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]     ###Get data frame reference in var
    ##++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    if isKdens:
        ###Set up layer file
        lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\\testFiles\\output\\AS_"+asno+"_KDens.lyr")
    ##++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    else:
        ###Set up layer file
        lyrFile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"F:\\testFiles\\output\\AS_"+asno+".lyr")
        lyrFile.visible = True
    ###Add layer file
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyrFile)

    ###ref added layer
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
    lyr.visible = True

    #If this is a raw map, just select points.
    if isKdens==0:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("pointslyr", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"asno\" = "+asno+"")
    ##++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    #If KDens map, apply symbology
    else:
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, templateLayer)
    ##++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    ###Zoom to selection
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    lyrExtent = lyr.getSelectedExtent()
    df.extent = lyrExtent

    ###Export to PDF!!!
    ##++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    if isKdens:
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"F:\\testFiles\\output\\AS_"+asno+"_KDens_Map.pdf")
    ##++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    else:
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"F:\\testFiles\\output\\AS_"+asno+"_Map.pdf")
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
#####DELETION
del mxd, df, lyrFile, lyrExtent, lyr
print "DELETED MXD AND DFS"
```

**EDIT 2**
So, I also tried [turning off logging](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/36750-Turning-on-off-geoprocessing-history-via-arcpy), since I have heard that can cause memory leaks, too. There is still something leaking. I also tried using `Delete_management` instead of `del`, but that just messes things up. It almost seems like my code is not running sequentially. A delete after a reference still gives a "references before defined" error...

Anyway, now I am trying to locate the memory leak using memory analyzer packages. Out of all of them that work with Python, I only got `objgraph` to work. I placed a `objgraph.show_growth` call before and after the function whose code is above. Here are the results:

**Before**

```
tuple                         11959    +11959
function                       3643     +3643
dict                           1632     +1632
wrapper_descriptor             1086     +1086
cell                            927      +927
list                            635      +635
builtin_function_or_method      590      +590
property                        551      +551
method_descriptor               390      +390
weakref                         373      +373
```

**After**

```
weakref                 398       +25
wrapper_descriptor     1105       +19
tuple                 11977       +18
dict                   1644       +12
member_descriptor       172        +4
getset_descriptor       213        +3
method_descriptor       392        +2
instance                 15        +2
list                    636        +1
`_RLock                    2        +1
```

It doesn't look like any of my objects are leaking, though I am not quite sure what `instance` means in the second growth dump. Anyone have any insights?

Comment: Maybe you could post some pseudocode?

Comment: Are you creating lots of MapDocument objects and not cleaning them up as you go by using **del**?

Comment: Also, where is the output of the kernel density going?

Comment: I have no experience of ArcPy, but some of the geoprocessing tools in earlier versions of ArcGIS do leak memory. Python does have garbage collection and, in my experience, memory leaks in ArcGIS scripts are rarely due to Python itself; they're either due to programmer error or to leaky geoprocessing tools. Some options for profiling memory consumption in your Python code are described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler)

Comment: @PolyGeo I have updated my original post to answer your question (as well as om_henners') and to provide a bit more information about my code.

Comment: @Aaron I have added the function in my code that is causing the problem.

Comment: You may be barking up the wrong tree with all the Python analysis; the underlying leak is probably in the C++/ArcObjects (which isn't covered). Try building up that code line-by-line, recording free/available memory before and after each function call.

Comment: @JasonScheirer Building up the C++ code from the ArcObjects? This may be a silly question, but how does one go about doing that?

Comment: I mean adding one line of the script at a time and running the profiler.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?  I'm running into the same problem.  I want to say its the mxd causing the memory leak.  But other than doing del mxd I'm not sure what else can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `Delete` tool. Call `arcpy.management.Delete("rdlayer")` after saving the layer file.

Comment: Thanks. I added this after saving the layer file, but python.exe still crashes. There must be some other leak elsewhere, but at least I took care of one of them!

Comment: export a pdf 2 times with the same mxd without arcpy block my arcmap. It maybe the same problem. I solution it by closing mxd and reopen